# Woocommerce - how to add big amount of variations?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I create an e-shop in Woocommerce and I have a problem with inserting variations. I have 20 colors (1-20) and 4 sizes (A-D), so total of 80 variations.

But my colors are in 3 different price groups (e. g. 1-7, 8-15 and 16-20) - so I need to set prices for every group and every size, e. g. like this:

```
  | 1-7 | 8-15 | 16-20 |
  ----------------------
A | $20 | $25  | $30   |
B | $30 | $35  | $40   |
C | $40 | $45  | $50   |
D | $50 | $55  | $60   |
```

I could create all combinations of these two factors, but that would be really difficult because there are 80 combinations in total.

So I would like to be able to select multiple colors for one variation (kind of *or* oparator), but it doesn't seem to be possible in pure Woocommerce.

How can I achieve inserting multiple colors as one variation without having to create a new variation for each color? Is there a plugin for this?

Comment: am not sure if there is plugin for that and normally here is not the place to get recommendation to a plugin :)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library, tutorial, book, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I think this is a valid question and there are so many questions asking for specific software. So why not for WooCommerce as well? Still, should have been able to solve this on your own with just a little bit of search engine usage. 
Maybe try the following plugin. At least my favorite for similar requirements: https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-fields/11332742

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with WooCommerce core.

You can try:

- simplify you pricing, so you don't need too many variations
- implement it on you own
- Use a plugin, you can apply rules

**Use a plugin**

i.e. [WooCommerce Custom Fields](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-fields/11332742)

Your rules would be something like this:

- Base price = 20
- if users = 1-7 -> add 0$, 8-15 -> add 5$ ...
- if A -> add 0$, B -> add 10$ ...

Comment: Thank you, I guess the best solution is gonna be to add new attribute "Color type" which is gonna be light, medium and dark, and set prices based on this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Products - Attributes - Add new and then add the following Attributes,
price, Alphabets, and Age
Once you made these three things click on each and add Prices in Price Alphabets in Alphabets Attribute and Ages in Ages Attribute. 
After doing this you can go to each every product and make it "Variable Products" and add those Attributes there.

Comment: I know about this, but I get 80 variations in total, which would be a pain in the ass to insert. So I'm looking for a way to group them together

Comment: Or else make one product with this attribute and then Export it in CSV and there you can add Products and Import it again on Website